# Oracle Apex 5.0.0 installation - getting an error while loading images

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, installation, oracle-apex

I installed Apex 5.0.0 and its coming VALID when i check its status.

When i am loading the image files I am getting the following error. My `C:\XXX\apex\images` path actually has the images. I checked the path. What else can be the issue ?

```
SQL> @apex_epg_config.sql C:\XXX
.Loading images directory: C:\XXX\apex\images
declare
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-22288: file or LOB operation FILEOPEN failed
No such file or directory
ORA-06512: at "SYS.XMLTYPE", line 296
ORA-06512: at line 16

declare
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-31001: Invalid resource handle or path name "/images"
ORA-06512: at "XDB.DBMS_XDB", line 473
ORA-06512: at line 58
```

Answer (score 1):

I presume that path you used is wrong.

From the documentation:

> **Configure the Embedded PL/SQL Gateway**
>
> Run the configuration script APEX_EPG_CONFIG passing the **file system path** to the **base
>   directory** where the Oracle Application Express software was
>   **unzipped**

It means that if you unzipped Apex software into `c:\xxx` and - as a result - got another subdirectory whose path is `c:\xxx\apex\...`, you have to specify `c:\xxx` as `apex_epg_config`'s parameter:

```
SQLPLUS /NOLOG
CONNECT SYS AS SYSDBA
@APEX_EPG_CONFIG C:\xxx
```

If you use `c:\xxx\apex` (or whichever directory it is), you WILL (and you DID) get

> ORA-22288: file or LOB operation FILEOPEN failed. The system cannot find the path specified.

(Not related to your problem, just to remind you - don't forget to `ALTER USER ANONYMOUS ACCOUNT UNLOCK`).

Comment: Thank you for your response @Littlefoot. 
I opened the cmd and did cd c:\xxx\apex. Over there i started and logged onto oracle. 
Then as you can see in the first line of my cmd I run the command exactly as you suggested with param as c:\xxx 
Also, i altered the user before running the config command as you suggested. 
I still got the same error.

Comment: Loading images directory: C:\XXX\apex\images

When I copy-paste the above path - C:\XXX\apex\images - in the file explorer it opens the correct folder where all the images are stored.

Comment: changing apex archive to C:/tmp/ worked for me also

Answer (score 0):

I've just had the same problem, albeit from Linux.

The file path I was using was correct, but the issue was the Oracle user didn't have permissions for the folder.

Temporarily, I've added read and execute permission for all users to my home folder /home/paulw (this is also the folder the apex was unzipped in).

The other issue I came across in the past on Windows was when there is a space in the directory path, it makes it more tricky and it's easier to just move the whole unzipped folder to the c:\

Finally the install can only be done the machine Oracle database is running on, due to the database pulling the images into the database (vs the sql for apex which pushes the code in). This is the same reason why I needed to fix permissions because it's the Oracle database ("oracle" user) pulling the images, rather than my logged on user "paulw" pushing the images.

Hope this is of some help, even if it's quite late!